# jenkins pipeline strategy - PR jobs and dev job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using github-branch-source-plugin for discovering pull requests. This plugin then create jobs and automatically run them whenever PR is added / updated.

I am also using normal jenkins pipeline to run develop branch (automatically, whenever PR is merged to dev).

I want to inject my application with branch name.

The problem is that BRANCH_NAME env variable is not available from jenkins pipeline.

It would be fine to configure github-branch-source-plugin so that it get all pull requests AND develop branch.
But it seems it is not possible? If I set "discover branches" and filter with "develop" then it filter out pull requests branches.

Am I missing sth?

Comment: so essentially your question is about getting the branch name in the pipeline?

Comment: I'm wondering why it's not accessible under `BRANCH_NAME`. But you can also try `env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME` IIRC. You can access a list of variables when you click the _Pipeline Syntax_ link in the left menu of your pipeline jobs.

Comment: @StephenKing yes, I need branch name. BRANCH_NAME => "For a *multibranch* project, this will be set to the name of the branch being built..."

Comment: Cool. Would you mind rephrasing your question then to make it a lot less complex to understand?

Comment: Further, please add the code that does not work for you. I use `BRANCH_NAME` successful in multibranch pipelines (with github plugins) for a while.